# REGISTRO CNAME A OTRO DOMINIO EN PLESK CON WILDCARD SUB DOMINIO

Tags: apache, dns, plesk

a ver si mi me dan algunas ideas para los iguiente:

He desarrollado un sistema de informacion con una funcionalidad de marca blanca.

Por ejemplo 
app.misistema.tld -> /www/app

Ahora bien, en el Plesk, he creado un subdominio con comodin que apunte a la misma carpeta, es decir:

*.misistema.tld -> /www/app

y en la DNS (por cierto es cloudflare) he creado un subdominio que apunte al document root del app, ejemplo:

dominios.misistema.tld

La pregunta es y que realmente no termina de funcionar que me gustaria en otros dominio crear un CNAME que apunte a dominios.misistema.tld

Es decir:

app.otrodominio.tld -> CNAME dominios.misistema.tld

Pero cuando entro en app.otrodominio.tld que debería de ir a /www/app no me termina de funcionar, sale el html por defecto de plesk.

No se por donde continuar, de hecho no se si es una configuración en el htaccess, apache, plesk, o si debo de añadir un alias de dominio en el plesk...

La idea tambien es no hacerle nada a la zona DNS de los dominios de los terceros, es decir en este ejemplo de misistema.tld

Alguna ayuda o ideas al respecto?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Nadie ......? :(

Comment: Parece que tu pregunta pasó desapercibida por la fecha en la que se hizo, te animo a que si tienes más dudas o quieres responder preguntas lo sigas haciendo ahora que han pasado las fiestas.

Comment: Gracias @ordago si... sin embargo, llegue a esta solucion, no como queria pero si es valida.

Answer (score 0):

Pues a la final tuve que seguir mirando como solucionarlo, y la unica forma es añadir en el Plesk un alias del dominio "app.otrodominio.tld", es decir puse en Apache aditional settings: ServerAlias app.otrodominio.tld

Tema Cerrado